# Automapper, INamingConvention Camelcase properties to uppercase with underscore

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have two classes one generetad by Entity Framework, the other is the class I use everywhere.

My Class :

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

EF class :

```
public class PERSON
{
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

I found the solution when the source is `PERSON` to `Person`, **but** I don't find the solution for `Person` to `PERSON` (the properties are in uppercase and underscore separator).

```
The solution for PERSON to Person :

Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<Profile1>());
var res = Mapper.Map<PERSON, Person>(person);

public class UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention : INamingConvention
{
    private readonly Regex _splittingExpression = new Regex(@"[p{Lu}0-9]+(?=_?)");
    public Regex SplittingExpression
    {
        get { return _splittingExpression; }
    }

    public string SeparatorCharacter
    {
        get { return "_"; }
    }
}

public class Profile1 : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        CreateMap<PERSON, Person>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using EF it has possibility to map fields to database fields, I mean no matter how they are called in database, you can give nice name in EF model, I think I would go this way. If you're using EF's dbml - it is plain xml, you can write xslt that would add field mapping before generating code, we use similar approach in Linq2Sql to replace some properties to enums, and if you're using T4 to generate code, you can tune it to generate right code.

Comment: In the database the field are all like this "FIRST_NAME", ok I can change in the EF model but it's almost the same work tha assign field by field with automapper with .ForMember

Comment: You won't need to duplicate classes though and as I said, it can be automated, depending on how you're using EF (in code first scenario maybe not so much).

Comment: Seems like possibly a bug in Automapper...

Answer (score 1):

This is working for version 7.0.1 of AutoMapper:

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Data.Service.Mapping
{
    public class UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention: INamingConvention
    {
        public Regex SplittingExpression { get; } = new Regex(@"[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}0-9]+(?=_?)");

        public string SeparatorCharacter => "_";

        public string ReplaceValue(Match match) => match.Value.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note for name conversion
**Target.AB** -> **Source.AB** but not **Source.A_B**
To fix this implement your **PascalCaseNamingConvention** with modifed RegExpression **(\p{Lu}(?=$|\p{Lu})|\p{Lu}?[\p{Ll}0-9]+)**

```
public class MyPascalCaseNamingConvention : INamingConvention
    {
        private static readonly Regex PascalCase = new Regex(@"(\p{Lu}(?=$|\p{Lu})|\p{Lu}?[\p{Ll}0-9]+)");
        public static readonly MyPascalCaseNamingConvention Instance = new MyPascalCaseNamingConvention();
        public Regex SplittingExpression { get; } = PascalCase;
        public string SeparatorCharacter => string.Empty;
        public string ReplaceValue(Match match) => match.Value[0].ToString().ToUpper() + match.Value.Substring(1);
    }
```