# Automapper omit CreateMap if naming convention is used

Tags: c#, automapper

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12000466/4699575) question, I want to know if I can omit `CreateMap<PERSON, Person>();`

I am using Automapper 7.0.1 and the profile has the following form

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        //...
        //...

        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        CreateMap<PERSON, Person>(); //what I want to omit

    }
}
```

I have noticed that if I remove this line `CreateMap<PERSON, Person>();` then only properties that don't contain any underscore get mapped and the mapper throws exception with the message that there are unmapped properties and a list of them.

Why do we want to use `CreateMap` when we want to map all properties based only on naming convention?

**EDIT:**

After @Lucian answer I removed naming convention from Profile and added it at initialization like this

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
    cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention();
    cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
});
```

Now I don't have to use `CreateMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default map (the one created by AM if you omit CreateMap) is global, it's certainly not in that profile you created. So setting the naming conventions on your profile doesn't help. Set the naming conventions on the global configuration.

Comment: I am initializing it like this `Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
            });` 
Can you show one sample how to set it globally?

Comment: Thank you! I removed naming convention from profile and added at initialization. It works now.